# Use TMX file with AndEngine

Tags: dictionary, background, andengine, isometric, tmx

I have an isometric .TMX file created with "Tiled", I'm using AndEngine GLES1. I want to use it as a background or map. I also want to have my "players" movement tied to the tiles if possible. I know that there are some questions dealing with this, but I need the actual code just to display the background.

Here is my only java file

```
package com.example.game;

 import java.util.LinkedList;

 import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
 import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.MoveModifier;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.IOnSceneTouchListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
  import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
 import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
 import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

 import android.view.Display;

 public class SimpleGame extends BaseGameActivity implements
IOnSceneTouchListener {
//Set up camera
private Camera mCamera;

//Set main scene
private Scene mMainScene;
//?? graphics variables?
private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private TextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;
//declaring sprite variable for player character
private Sprite player;
//Equiping ammunition
private LinkedList projectileLL;
private LinkedList projectilesToBeAdded;
private TextureRegion mProjectileTextureRegion;


@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    //Preparing Engine giving it proper resolution (what you see on the screen)
    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int cameraWidth = display.getWidth();
    int cameraHeight = display.getHeight();

     mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, cameraWidth, cameraHeight);

    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE,
    new RatioResolutionPolicy(cameraWidth, cameraHeight), mCamera));
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
    mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512,
        TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    // assinging the player.png image for the mPlayerTextureRegion
    mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
        .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "player.png",
        0, 0);
    mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mBitmapTextureAtlas);

    mProjectileTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
        .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this,
        "Projectile.png", 64, 0);
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    //??? Creating the scene?
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    mMainScene = new Scene();

    mMainScene
        .setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

    final int PlayerX = this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getWidth() / 2;
    final int PlayerY = (int) ((mCamera.getHeight() - mPlayerTextureRegion
            .getHeight()) / 2);

    // Using sprite to illustrate player
    player = new Sprite(PlayerX, PlayerY, mPlayerTextureRegion);
    // Place player on game screen
    mMainScene.attachChild(player);

    projectileLL = new LinkedList();
    projectilesToBeAdded = new LinkedList();

    mMainScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);

    return mMainScene;
}
     // This method is used for shooting "bullets"
    // Need to find a way to limit ammunition based on in game inventory
      private void shootProjectile(final float pX, final float pY) {

int offX = (int) (pX - player.getX());
int offY = (int) (pY - player.getY());
if (offX <= 0)
    return;

//Using projectile.png as sprite, what is .deepCopy???
final Sprite projectile;
projectile = new Sprite(player.getX(), player.getY(),
mProjectileTextureRegion.deepCopy());
mMainScene.attachChild(projectile, 1);

int realX = (int) (mCamera.getWidth() + projectile.getWidth() / 2.0f);
float ratio = (float) offY / (float) offX;
int realY = (int) ((realX * ratio) + projectile.getY());

int offRealX = (int) (realX - projectile.getX());
int offRealY = (int) (realY - projectile.getY());
float length = (float) Math.sqrt((offRealX * offRealX)
        + (offRealY * offRealY));
float velocity = 480.0f / 1.0f; // 480 pixels per 1 sec//
float realMoveDuration = length / velocity;

MoveModifier mod = new MoveModifier(realMoveDuration,
projectile.getX(), realX, projectile.getY(), realY);
projectile.registerEntityModifier(mod.deepCopy());

projectilesToBeAdded.add(projectile);
    }

public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        final float touchX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
        final float touchY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
        shootProjectile(touchX, touchY);
        return true;
    }
return false;
}


@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {


}
    }
```

EDIT
After switching to GLES2 this is giving me some errors. I'm using a new class and inserting the provided code. Do I need to create classes for any of these? Is linking the TMXproject done via properties - android and the "add" box at the bottom of that page?? Thanks

```
package com.example.game;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;

public class StarterGame extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private Object tiledMap;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    //Create view for the scene??
    Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR,
            new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        final TMXLoader tmxLoader = new TMXLoader(context.getAssets(), textureManager, TextureOptions.NEAREST, vertexBufferObjectManager, new ITMXTilePropertiesListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTMXTileWithPropertiesCreated(final TMXTiledMap pTMXTiledMap, final TMXLayer pTMXLayer, final TMXTile pTMXTile, final TMXProperties<TMXTileProperty> pTMXTileProperties) {
                    // do stuff with tiles that have properties...
            }
        });
        this.tiledMap = tmxLoader.loadFromAsset("tmx/bg.tmx");
          this.tiledMap.setIsometricDrawMethod(TMXIsometricConstants.DRAW_METHOD_ISOMETRIC_CULLING_PADDING);
    } catch (final TMXLoadException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    //Setup scene with background color only
    Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0));
    return scene;
}

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I can only show you how I do it with the AndEngine GLES2. I am not sure though, that this is possible with the GLES1 Version. But maybe you can try an tell us about your experience.

**first** download the TMX Tilemap Extension from the Git repository: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension

**second** link your project with the *AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension* Project (it needs to be marked as a Library)

When these two projects are linked you can actually use the Extension like this:

```
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLayer;
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLoader;
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLoader.ITMXTilePropertiesListener;
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXProperties;
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXTile;
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXTileProperty;
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXTiledMap;
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.util.constants.TMXIsometricConstants;
 import org.andengine.extension.tmx.util.exception.TMXLoadException;


 public class YourActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
     private TMXTiledMap tiledMap;
     private TMXLayer tmxLayer;

     @Override
     protected void onCreateResources() {
       try {
           final TMXLoader tmxLoader = new TMXLoader(getAssets(), getTextureManager(), TextureOptions.NEAREST, getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new ITMXTilePropertiesListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTMXTileWithPropertiesCreated(final TMXTiledMap tmxTiledMap, final TMXLayer tmxLayer, final TMXTile tmxTile, final TMXProperties<TMXTileProperty> tmxTileProperties) {
                    // do stuff with tiles that have properties...
            }
           });
           this.tiledMap = tmxLoader.loadFromAsset("tmx/yourMap.tmx");
           this.tiledMap.setIsometricDrawMethod(TMXIsometricConstants.DRAW_METHOD_ISOMETRIC_CULLING_PADDING);
       } catch (final TMXLoadException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
       }

     }

     @Override
     protected Scene onCreateScene() {
           this.tmxLayer = this.tiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(0);  // the 0 is just an index of the layer. It depends on how many layers you created within Tiled
           attachChild(this.tmxLayer);
     }

 }
```

When you included your isometric map you may see some pixel artifacts (black lines, where the tiles come together) – its a common problem and there is a fix for it at:
http://code.google.com/p/andenginetmxtiledmapartifactfixer/
here you find a java program with which you can load your map file and that will produce a fixed map that you can use in your project. Look under **usage** to see which parameters you need.

hope this helps anyway :)

christoph

Comment: Christoph, thanks for the answer. I'm just going to port to GLES2, I need to anyway and I was getting issues trying to link the TMXextension with GLES1.

Comment: GLES2 really works fine. I hope you don't have too much trouble porting. If you have problems to get that TMX thing going, just tell me - I would be glad to share the experience I made, even if it is not mouch ;)

Comment: Christoph, I've changed to GLES2, got all the extensions loaded as library projects and linked to my project. But I'm getting errors on some of these commands. Like it says that "new TMXLoader" is deprecated. Then it's giving me errors on context.getAssets(), vertexBufferObjectManager. And also on some of the isometric stuff. If you could help me that would be awesome.

Comment: I edited the code a little bit, hoping that it is more clear now. the `getAssets()` and ` getVertexBufferObjectManager()` methods are methods from the Activity, so you may want to use this code within your Activity. But you can also use it in a separate Scene (as I did it. Thats why they where different).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I still can't get it working. I've imported Niffy's Isometric branch TMXTiledMapExtension and example (did not clone submodules) and I've gotten the code in eclipse with no errors. (although I had to change the attachChild(this.tmxLayer) a little as it was giving me errors. But I'm getting a force close for some reason. My TMX map was gzip compressed, does it need to be XML or something?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the main `TMXExtension`, first by pulling the repo down (I think clone).  Then add a remote using my [repo url](https://github.com/Niffy/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension).

Then you want to pull down the isometric branch and check it out.

A good place for learning git is [here](http://git-scm.com/book).